How to make a function "globally available"?
I am following the instructions to use the pre-built OAuth Google Login with NextJs for use with SupaBase.
Step 4 says:

Create a handleSignInWithGoogle function that takes the CredentialResponse and passes the included token to Supabase. The function needs to be available in the global scope for Google's code to find it.

How do I make a function available in global scope?  I tried to wrap my callback function in a  tag in the root, but maybe that's the old school HTML way...
<script>
      async function handleSignInWithGoogle(response) {
        const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signInWithIdToken({
          provider: 'google',
          token: response.credential,
        })
      }
</script>

this results in an error:
Error: 
  × Unexpected token `html`. Expected jsx identifier
    ╭─[/Users/lucksp/dev/identafly-www/app/layout.tsx:23:1]
 23 │   children: React.ReactNode,
 24 │ }) {
 25 │   return (
 26 │     <html lang="en" className={GeistSans.className} suppressHydrationWarning>
    ·      ────
 27 │       <body className="bg-background text-foreground">
 28 │         <ThemeProvider
 29 │           attribute="class"
    ╰────

What's the correct way to do this?

Did you try adding that function directly inside the top level component in main file of your next project?
Something like _app.tsx

Have you tried window.handleSignInWithGoogle = handleSignInWithGoogle  That would truly be the global scope.

yes, but Next didn't compile.  I have since moved on to just use my own button
